# how I can link Multiple Checkboxes with button to open page in html and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How I can link Multiple Checkboxes with button to open page in HTML and JavaScript?
I Need When I am Choice Multiple Checkboxes and press The Button All Links open In the Same Time

```css
a{
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
<label for="">Open google</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
<label for="">Open youtube</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
<label for="">Open twitter</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
<label for="">Open reddit</label>
<a href="#">open</a>
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCVIn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want... but this method wont work as you expect on modern browsers without client actually allowing popups on your page

Live Preview: https://playcode.io/936274/

```js
// Native Version
const button = document.querySelector("a");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

  if (checked) {
    checked.forEach((el) => {
      window.open(el.value, '_blank');
    });
  }
});

// JQuery Version
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    window.open($(this).val(), "_blank")
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="https://google.com">
<label for="">Open google</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="https://youtube.com">
<label for="">Open youtube</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="https://twitter.com">
<label for="">Open twitter</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="https://reddit.com">
<label for="">Open reddit</label>
<a href="#">open</a>
```

Comment: Thx For This Answer But When I am a Choice Multiple Checkboxes In The Same Time It's Don't Work I Need When Iam press Multiple Checkboxes In The Same Time All Links Open In The Same Time In New Taps (google, youtube, twitter, reddit).

Comment: As i wrote in description, you cannot achieve this on modern browser since there is popup guard. Client must allow popups on your page to be able to open all those links in same time.